# JQuery's action go to start when I reload the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to make a slider for my menu. It should be above the actually active menuitem.
I can’t really show my problem in codepen. But I can show my jquery:

https://codepen.io/Ayalann/pen/xrrjgg

I got this code from codepen

```js
$("ul li").click(function(e) {

  // make sure we cannot click the slider
  if ($(this).hasClass('slider')) {
    return;
  }

  /* Add the slider movement */

  // what tab was pressed
  var whatTab = $(this).index();

  // Work out how far the slider needs to go
  var howFar = 160 * whatTab;

  $(".slider").css({
    left: howFar + "px"
  });

  /* Add the ripple */

  // Remove olds ones
  $(".ripple").remove();

  // Setup
  var posX = $(this).offset().left,
      posY = $(this).offset().top,
      buttonWidth = $(this).width(),
      buttonHeight = $(this).height();

  // Add the element
  $(this).prepend("<span class='ripple'></span>");

  // Make it round!
  if (buttonWidth >= buttonHeight) {
    buttonHeight = buttonWidth;
  } else {
    buttonWidth = buttonHeight;
  }

  // Get the center of the element
  var x = e.pageX - posX - buttonWidth / 2;
  var y = e.pageY - posY - buttonHeight / 2;

  // Add the ripples CSS and start the animation
  $(".ripple").css({
    width: buttonWidth,
    height: buttonHeight,
    top: y + 'px',
    left: x + 'px'
  }).addClass("rippleEffect");
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700);
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background: #222;
}

ul {
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  width: 480px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  user-select: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #39CCCC;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background: yellow;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*  Ripple */

.ripple {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  transform: scale(0);
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}

.rippleEffect {
  animation: rippleDrop .6s linear;
}

@keyframes rippleDrop {
  100% {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item Three</li>
  <li class="slider"></li>
</ul>
```

My problem is when I click on the menu item in my page, the slider is moving but when the new page is downloaded the slider go to the start. It doesn’t stay above the active menu item.

That is why I tried to do this:

```
  if ($(".sf-main-menu li").hasClass("active-trail")) {
  $(".slider").css({
    left: howFar + "px"
  });
```

But it doesn’t work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: you need to pass the active class to the tab on the next page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function and pass the active li in it for positioning slider and call same function when you click on a list like,

```js
$(function() {
  function menuChange(ths) {
    // make sure we cannot click the slider
    /* if ($(this).hasClass('slider')) {
       return;
     }*/
    /* Add the slider movement */

    // what tab was pressed
    var whatTab = $(ths).index();

    // Work out how far the slider needs to go
    var howFar = 100 * whatTab;

    /* $(".slider").css({
       left: howFar + "px"
     });*/

    if ($(".sf-main-menu li").hasClass("active-trail")) {
      $(".slider").css({
        left: howFar + "px"
      });

    }

  }
  $(".sf-main-menu li").click(function() {
    menuChange(this);
  });
  menuChange($(".sf-main-menu li.active-trail"));
  $('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  border-top: 3px solid green;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  opacity: .8;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
}

.sf-main-menu li {
  position: relative;
}

.sf-menu .active {
  color: green;
}

.sf-menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.sf-menu a {
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="superfish-1" class="menu sf-menu sf-main-menu sf-horizontal sf-style-none sf-total-items-4 sf-parent-items-0 sf-single-items-4 superfish-processed sf-js-enabled">
  <li id="menu-2025-1" class="first odd sf-item-1 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children"><a href="/fooldal" title="" class="sf-depth-1">Főoldal</a></li>
  <li id="menu-396-1" class="active-trail middle even sf-item-2 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children"><a href="/hirek" class="sf-depth-1 active">Hírek</a></li>
  <li id="menu-399-1" class="middle odd sf-item-3 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children"><a href="/magunkrol" class="sf-depth-1">Magunkról</a></li>
  <li id="menu-400-1" class="last even sf-item-4 sf-depth-1 sf-no-children"><a href="/kapcsolat" class="sf-depth-1">Kapcsolat</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Comment: You need to remove code `$('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });` It was just for testing.

Comment: Oh, yes! Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Actually It is not perfect. Somehow the slider moves twice, when I click and when the new page is downloaded.

Comment: Comment the code `$(".sf-main-menu li").click(function() {
    menuChange(this);
  });
` and try.